# Use of 'import * as' in combination with index.ts

Tags: typescript, import, module

I was reading an article on [the use of index.ts files](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/smarter-way-to-organize-import-statements-using-index-ts-file-s-in-angular-c685e9d645b7) in Modular Angular development. I found it rather useful. This can reduce the number of import statements drastically. But it requires you to include all referred components in a single line.

So when we initially have

```
import {BusinessLogicComponent} from '../shared/ang-graph/shapes/business-logic.component';
import {BusinessLogicModel} from '../shared/ang-graph/shapes/business-logic.model';
import {PageReferenceComponent} from '../shared/ang-graph/shapes/page-reference.component';
import {PageReferenceModel} from '../shared/ang-graph/shapes/page-reference.model';
import {RestRequestComponent} from '../shared/ang-graph/shapes/rest-request.component';
import {RestRequestModel} from '../shared/ang-graph/shapes/rest-request.model';
```

we could reduce this to

```
import {BusinessLogicComponent, BusinessLogicModel, PageReferenceComponent, PageReferenceModel, RestRequestComponent, RestRequestModel} from '../shared/ang-graph/shapes';
```

But this gives a very long line of code which is not really readable.

So I was wondering if it is OK to replace the above reduced import statement with for example:

```
import * as GraphShapes from '../shared/ang-graph/shapes';
```

This makes all more readable again, with the added bonus of having a better knowledge of the origin of the component in the code.

So

```
const pageRef = new PageReferenceModel('page1', def, 'some-prop');
```

would become

```
const pageRef = new GraphShapes.PageReferenceModel('page1', def, 'some-prop');
```

I think this is more clear in the code, but I'm not sure if there are bad side effects to this approach, such as importing too much components or...

So, is this a good practice to use

```
import * as [GroupName] from 'path/to/code/folder';
```

in combination with `index.ts` files?

Answer (score 0):

Using `index.ts` to list "public interface" of you code package is a good idea.

Though *-imports are not that good from long term codebase maintenance perspective: in case of large packages `index.ts` may include tens of exported elements and *-import makes it harder to navigate the code.

In case you import specific names - anybody on the team can trace which classes/functions are imported in every file.

Comment: "*-import makes it harder to navigate the code." I do not see why. IDE's like WebStorm provide easy navigation which keeps on working with the *-import approach. It even adds the benefit of getting a complete list of available components when typing "GraphShapes." followed by for example ALT+SPACE to invoke auto completion.

Comment: Agreed, though I suggest not to use *-imports for several reasons: a) not everybody is on WebStorm; b) it's convenient to see all imported code elements on the top; c) code review tools usually do not have such extensive language support (e.g. if your team is doing PR review on github/gitlab).